# Date picker and time picker should be separate

Tags: html, laravel

Herein, a textfield format `2018-05-22 00:00:00` which for `dateTime` columns in my DB. I am trying to make it two textfield without change into my table wherein **one is for date(date-picker)** and **another is for time**.

```html
<div class="form-group col-lg-5">
                {!! Form::label('tradedate', 'Traded date:') !!}
                <div class=" input-append date form_datetime" data-date="{{date('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
                    <input size="16" type="text" value="" readonly class="form-control">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input1" value="" name="tradedate" />
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think issue is that you are not using any sort of function for your **date-date-format** attribute.

```
  <div class=" input-append date form_datetime" data-date="{{date('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}" data-date-format="{{date('dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p')}}" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
```

Just for information in laravel you can use Carbon to deal with date and times. We can do date logic very easily using it. Link below: https://carbon.nesbot.com

Hope , it helps...thanks..cheers.